# PHP Accessing variables stored in an object in a class

Tags: php, class, properties, getter-setter

I have just dived in to php objects and trying to set/get some properties.

I think i am understanding getters and setters and magic methods, at least the pros an conns of using them. (i'm using a magic method right now, so i have less code to maintain while i learn, and also i am not sure how many bits of info i need to store about my user)

I would like to have my $_userdata as an object with a set of properties.
loggedin (true false)
firstname(firstname of user)
lastname (lastname of user)
....and others

I am having problems setting and getting values

```
require_once('facebook/facebook.php'); // require facebook sdk
require_once('config.class.php'); // require config class
require_once('dbconn.class.php'); //require database connector

class user{
    public $_userData; // holds information of our user
    private $conn; // our database connection
    public $facebook; // facebook sdk
    public $fbuser; // the facebook user
    //Constructor
    public function __construct(Array $properties=array()) {
        $this->conn = DBconn::getInstance(); //get DB instance
        $this->facebook = new Facebook(Config::read('fb.facebook'));
        $this->_userData = $properties;
    }

    // magic methods for reading/writing our user properties!
    public function __set($property, $value){
        return $this->_userData[$property] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($property){
        return array_key_exists($property, $this->_userData)? 
            $this->_userData[$property]: 
            null
        ;        
    }
    /**
    * getSession - saves session vars to our user
    * @return bool: true - session retrieved
    *               false - no session found
    */
    public function getSession(){
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            //save session to this user
            $this->_userData->email = $_SESSION['email'];
            $this->_userData->loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
            $this->_userData->provider = $_SESSION['provider'];
            $this->_userData->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
            //something wrong as the properties dont get set!!!!
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function getProfile(){
        //first set the users profile information
        try{
            $pdoQuery = ("SELECT
                email_upl as'email',
                firstname_upl as 'firstname',
                lastname_upl as 'lastname',
                username_upl as 'username',
                image_upl as 'image',
                info_upl as 'info'
                FROM userprofile_upl
                WHERE email_upl = :email"
            );
            $stmt = $this->conn->dbh->prepare($pdoQuery);
            //this->_userdata->email returns null...
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->_userData->email); 
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            // row has no data because the email property has no value!!!
            //var_dump($row); 
            $this->_userData->email = $row->email;
            $this->_userData->firstname= $row->firstname;
            $this->_userData->lastname = $row->lastname;
            $this->_userData->info = $row->info;
            return (true);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo('There was an error while connecting to your profile<br>');
            return false;
        }
    }
/**
     * loginFacebook - Logs a user into the site with facebook
     * Checks to see if user has an account and if not make one.
     * Checks to see if user has a profile and if not make one.
     * Checks to see if user has facebook credentials on this site
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function loginFacebook(){
        $fbuser = $this->facebook->getUser();//get facebook user
        if($fbuser){// if we have a user returned we have user who's authenticated and logged in with facebook
            try { // Proceed knowing we have a user.
                $me = $this->facebook->api('/me'); // the facebook user
                //generate a log-out url
                $params = array( 'next' => config::read('url.logout'));
                //set user logout_url
                $this->_userData->logout_url = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
                //set the users details
                // this values are not getting set
                // so when the setSession is called it has no values to poulate the session with
                $this->_userData->uid = $this->facebook->getUser();
                $this->_userData->firstname = $me['first_name'];
                $this->_userData->lastname = $me['last_name'];
                $this->_userData->email = $me['email'];
                $this->_userData->provider = 'facebook';
                var_dump($this->_userData);
                if(!$this->fbAccountExists($this->_userData)){
                    //$this->fbCreateAccount($this->_userData);
                };
                if(!$this->profileExists()){
                    //$this->createProfile();
                }
                var_dump($this->_userData);
                $this->setSession();
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException $e){ //if theres an error
                $fbuser = null; //set the user to nothing
                return false();
            }
        }
        if(!$fbuser){
            //get a login url, returns to this page so we can process the login($fblogin_url)
            $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>Config::read('url.fblogin'), false));
            header('Location: '.$loginUrl);//redirect to the login page
        }
    }

}
```

usage:

```
$user = new user(); // create a new user
$user->getSession(); //get the user from the session
var_dump($user->_userData); // data contains null values
```

The session contains the following data

> ["loggedIn"]=> bool(true)
>   ["email"]=> NULL 
>   ["uid"]=> NULL ["provider"]=> NULL }

The user object contains no data

> $this->_userData
>   array(0) { }

So the problem lies within the initial loginFacebook method not setting the properties.

the setters are not working there....

Comment: Is the session present and logged in?  Do you have error reporting turned up and `display_errors` on? Always in development: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` The `_userData` object is uninitialized so you may see warnings about that.

Comment: i have included the initila login function, the facebook data should be set as properties for`_userData' but it seems not to be happening so when other methods call the data from _user they get null values.
I'm not sure if my getter setter methods are gorrect

Comment: Looks like `["loggedIn"]=> bool(true)` is what you have, but `$_SESSION['loggedin'] == true` is what you test. Array keys are case sensitive.  Next though, your `__set()` sets array keys but you otherwise use object properties. You're probably going to need `$this->_userData->{$property} = $value;` instead of `[$property]` after debugging the session part...

Comment: ok thanks for that, if i declare `_userData` as `new stdClass`, can i get/set without using the `{}` ?

Comment: You don't actually need the `{}` unless you had a complex thing in there like `$_userData->{$array['key']}` as a property name. You can just use `$this->userData->$property`

Comment: The way i was doing it seemed more complicated than it should be, i set `$_userData` as a `new stdClass` now i have done that i can set using: `$this->_userData->myproperty = 'new value'` and get with: '$this->_userData->myproperty` i dont even need the setter getter magic method, as it seems to be built in to the `stdClass()`

Comment: You don't need the magic setter and getter if you are just modifying them in the class. They would be useful if outside the class you wanted to do something like `$user->property = 'newvalue'` and have that stored in `_userData` with `private` visibility as `$this->_userData->property = 'newvalue'`. For use only inside the class though, it's true it just complicates things.